# Can I declare a function inside a LINQ select clause?

Tags: linq, select, func

I'm studying for MS Exam 70-483 (C#) and this idea occurred to me.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}

class City
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

/* assume code to populate List people and List cities */

```
var personsByCity = from p in people join c in cities
   on p.CityId equals c.Id
   select new { PersonName = p.Name, CityName = c.Name,
        ToString = Func<string>( () => { return PersonName + "/" +
               CityName; })};
```

The compiler error that occurs is "[CS0119] Expression denotes a `type' where a`variable' or `method group' was expected.

Resharper is a bit clearer: Delegate name is not valid at this point (i.e. where Func occurs).

So, is there a way to accomplish adding a function to an anonymous type in a LINQ query?

Comment: Not an answer but, I think you would need `PersonName` as `p.Name` rather than `c.Name` .

Comment: Thank you! Too late at nite for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can declare a function, but you can't define it to return a property of the anonymous type that is currently being declared-- if you were to use `this`, for example, the lambda would capture the value of `this` in the declaring context (the class that contains the code that is executing the LINQ). You can however capture the values that are being used to initialize the anonymous class (as I do in the example below).

Note that this is ***not*** the same as giving the anonymous class a method. Anonymous classes can only have read-only, immutable properties. In this case, your anonymous class will still have the original `ToString()` method inherited from `object`. This may make it [tricky to distinguish the function held in the `ToString` property from the `ToString()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890274/how-to-call-a-method-when-its-masked-by-an-invocable-property), so maybe you should use a different name.

Also, you forgot the `new` keyword before `Func`.

```
var personsByCity = from p in people join c in cities on p.CityId equals c.Id
    select new 
    {
        PersonName = p.Name, 
        CityName = c.Name,
        ToString = new Func<string>( () => { 
            return c.Name + "/" + p.Name; 
        })
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch (new). I thought about depending on Object.ToString(), I even thought some about an extension method. It just seems to be a logical extension, the ability to define instance methods AND properties in the projection.