# How to call a method when it's masked by an invocable property?

Tags: c#, .net

Disclaimer: I know this example is sort of ridic; just want to know what the language will allow me to do if this bizarre situation were ever to come up.

Consider the following short example:

```
var anonymous = new 
{
    ToString = new Func<string>( () => { return "This came from my property.";} )
};
Console.WriteLine(anonymous);
Console.WriteLine(anonymous.ToString());
```

The output is a little surprising:

```
{ ToString = System.Func`1[System.String] }
This came from my property.
```

Apparently when I called `ToString()`, c# decided to

1. Resolve the symbol `ToString` to the property called `ToString`
2. Retrieve its value, which is a Func
3. Execute the function and retrieve its return value

What language constructs are available that would enable me to call the `ToString()` ***method*** instead of the `ToString` property's result?

Note: I'm not trying to override `ToString()` (I realize it is impossible), I just want to know how to call `ToString()` instead of invoking the property's return value.

Comment: [quote]I'm not trying to override ToString() (I realize it is impossible)[/quote] In fact it's impossible for anonymous types in C#.

Answer (score 5):

On your anonymous object, in contexts where the compiler has full static typing information, the `ToString` method is shadowed by your property. However, shadowing is not the same thing as overriding: when it's downcast to `Object`, the identically-named property disappears and the original implementation of `ToString` is visible again.

You are seeing a difference because `Console.WriteLine` sees an `object` instead of the most precise statically-known type. This allows it to ignore shadowing and call the virtual `ToString` method instead.

You can do it yourself, too:

```
object foo = anonymous;
foo.ToString();
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/SFF56319).

Comment: But wait, is it possible for a property to shadow a method? Or does this have something to do with the anonymous types?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it is evidently possible, although it generates a warning in actual class definitions.